# Source Installation after a Debian Installation

Tags: ros, installation, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am referring to the Turtlebot installation process on http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation

I did a Debian installation for the Turtlebot but realized that I should have done a Source installation instead. If I were to do a source installation now, will it create any errors during the overwrite process?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250965/source-installation-after-a-debian-installation/) by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-30**:
Just curious: can you tell us why you feel you "should have done a Source installation instead"?

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2016-12-30**:
Source installation allows me to access and edit the codes whereas for a debian installation, it isn't so straightforward to access the codes right? (Do correct me if I am wrong, I'm pretty new to ROS).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Source installation allows me to access and edit the codes whereas for a debian installation, it isn't so straightforward to access the codes right?

You can create a Catkin workspace in which you place just the packages you want the sources for / edit. Those will *overlay* the binary packages, so if something isn't present in your workspace, the binary will be used. No need to redo your installation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3